# Type of tokens used to authenticate rest api

Tags: rest, jwt, api-key

I have been searching some way to genereta tokens on the client side. But I'm really stuck here, I'm trying to do a rest api to do some internet of things, I had been seen how other platforms do they authentication methods, but really don't catch them, so I was looking for JWT but it is to long for this purpose. This is an example of some tokens on other platforms, they have an Api Key from where you can generate a token to do the correspondent http request.
Here is an example of a token generated:

```
4YjYQOqR8MRjRIamTqy2LSQYsscNHO
```

And another token:

```
sub-c-bd2c3600-9e31-11e6-9194-0619f8945a4f
```

And an example of JWT token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImRpZWdvLm1heW9yZ2E4NkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJyb2xlIjpbIlVzZXIiXSwiaWQiOiI1ODExMmRkZjFkMzRhOTZiOGIxY2MwODAiLCJpYXQiOjE0Nzc3NzkyMTV9.bD62WQv_Q16tegZDejuDS435LOn1awGyh20Npi7166w
```

Ok so I've thinking to use JWT with a localStorage or cookies or session when the user is using the platform, and for http request from different devices like smart phones and arduino, use bcrypt so the user can generate random tokens starting from an API Key.

I'm trying to do a REST Api, the backend I'm doing with nodejs, specifically the hapijs framework and the front end I will do with React or Angular.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard provide a good solution without a few more pieces of information about the problem at hand. What is the client in this case? If you are building some type of web(site/app) then the generation code is being exposed to the user which is a big security problem. If this is something taking place in a standalone compiled application that the user wouldn't be able to access without the original source used to produce the binary being run on the client then all you have to do is choose a generation with a definitive inverse; jwt, rsa, aes, des, ect are all examples of modern encryption algorithms. JWT's are made up of 3 parts [token = encodeBase64(header) + '.' + encodeBase64(payload) + '.' + encodeBase64(signature)] and can have an arbitrarily sized json payload which is what makes them a bit larger but you will have this issue with many methods if you would like the token to relay more then just a true or false value (which is most likely the case). If you are interacting with external resources I would suggest you generate these tokens on a separate service inaccessible to the user.

Comment: in the front end will be Angular or React and some aplications in android or arduino.